# Boost.Test - Undefined symbol when overriding main

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I want to provide my own main function while using Boost.Test. So I have included the following macros:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_ALTERNATIVE_INIT_API
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
```

My main function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int exitCode = ::boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(&initialise, argc, argv);

    return exitCode;
}
```

I have also created the function `initialise`.

When built on OS X using Xcode 6 the following error is reported:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(bool (*)(), int, char**)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
```

I am linking-in the unit test framework library.

Can someone please help resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1) Include `<boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>` in the test module. This has the effect of building both the test framework and the test module simultaneously.

2) Rebuild the test framework library with`BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN`and `BOOST_TEST_ALTERNATIVE_INIT_API`.

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/practical_usage_recommendations/general.html) the 2nd option is preferred.